# had his brow in his hands

Tags: meaning

What does **had his brow in his hands** mean?

> It sounded like a very troubled forty-year-old man, a man who had **had
>   his brow in his hands** a long time.

Testimony of Pilot
by Barry Hannah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to put the palms of your hands above your eyes near your brows.

One would usually do it when they are frustrated.

Google for frustration and go to image section, you will get it.